# Graphing Data from SQL database using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph

I have a csv file in the following format:

```
INDEX_NAME,IDXQ_DATE,INDEX_VALUE

FTSE 100TL,30-Apr-19,100.000

FTSE 100TL,01-May-19,100.446

FTSE 100TL,02-May-19,100.849

FTSE 100TL,03-May-19,100.449

S & P 500TL,30-Apr-19,100.000

S & P 500TL,01-May-19,100.755

S & P 500TL,02-May-19,100.965

S & P 500TL,03-May-19,99.992

MSCI WorldTL,30-Apr-19,100.000

MSCI WorldTL,01-May-19,100.398

MSCI WorldTL,02-May-19,100.784

MSCI WorldTL,03-May-19,100.002
```

I have imported said CSV into Pandas as a DataFrame and I am now looking to graph the index performance (for each unique index) across the 4 days present. I would like all data to be on the same plot.

I have tried extracting part of the dataframe into seperate entities to try and the graph them separately but to no avail. Essentially I need help in manipulating the DataFrame into an easy way to graph or secondly a method to graph the data as it is presented - if possible.

Starting from a low knowledge base so unfortunately, any attempts I've made won't be too helpful!

x-axis to show idxq_date
y-axis to show index_values

Graph of each individual entity over time to be show on figure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plt.figure()
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv').set_index('IDXQ_DATE')
df.groupby('INDEX_NAME')['INDEX_VALUE'].plot(legend=True)
```